# Calling a SAPUI5 control from a view works, embedded in a XMLComposite control does not (global external library)

Tags: javascript, sapui5, amcharts

I am trying to build a amCharts Container control, a UI5 control with a graph built via amCharts. Generally speaking it works but I am sure you can spot a lot of hacks that could be done better.

My biggest problem at the moment is that when I use the control from within another XMLComposite control I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: am4core is not defined at f.onAfterRendering
>   (AmChartContainer.js?eval:38)

Debugging the code proofs that the jQuery.sap.includeScript is executed before, still the global element am4core is not available. When I embed the control directly into the view, it works though.

The other thing I am not happy with is the event order. Would love to instantiate the amchart inside the render method but at that point in time there is no htmlelement, which the amchart instantiation needs. Agreed?

Would appreciate any pointers!

```
sap.ui.define([ 'sap/ui/core/Control', "jquery.sap.global" ], function(Control, jQuery) {
    return Control.extend("io.rtdi.amChartContainer", {
        metadata: {
            properties: {
                width: {
                    type: "sap.ui.core.CSSSize",
                    defaultValue: "100%"
                },
                height: {
                    type: "sap.ui.core.CSSSize",
                    defaultValue: "100%"
                },
                plugin: {
                    type: "string"
                }
            },
            aggregations : {},
        },
        renderer : function(oRm, oControl) {
            oRm.write("<div");
            oRm.write(" style=\"width: " + oControl.getWidth() + 
                       "; height: " + oControl.getHeight() + ";\" ");
            oRm.writeControlData(oControl);
            oRm.write(">");
            oRm.write("</div>");
        },
        onBeforeRendering : function() {
            jQuery.sap.includeScript("https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js",
                "amCharts.core", null, null);
            jQuery.sap.includeScript("https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js",
                "amCharts.charts", null, null);
            if (!!this.getPlugin()) {
                jQuery.sap.includeScript(
                       "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/" + this.getPlugin(), 
                       "amCharts.plugin", null, null);
            }
        },
        onAfterRendering : function() {
            // if I need to do any post render actions, it will happen here
            if (sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
                sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            this._chart = am4core.create(this.getId(), am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree);
        },
        getChart: function() {
            return this._chart;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please use [sap/ui/dom/includeScript](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/module:sap/ui/dom/includeScript) since jQuery.sap.includeScript is considered deprecated.

You do not have any fnLoadCallback defined. Are you 100% sure, that the scripts are already loaded and am4core is defined, when onAfterRendering is called?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the global keyword at the beginning was the missing piece:

```
/* global am4core:true */
/* global am4charts:true */
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",...
```